# Dúvida em uma expressão lambda retornando "true"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Quando eu faço isso:

```
List<Tipo1> tipo = await context.MeuMetodo.Find(x => true).ToListAsync();
```

O que eu estou dizendo aqui: `(x => true)`?

Comment: é Hibernate? ...

Comment: Olha qual é o banco de dados? esse código aparentemente é estranho (não precisa fazer find e depois `ToListAsync` já é direto !!! No MongoDB existe `Find` assim mas, Entity Framework eu desconheço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neste contexto que deve pegar tudo, portanto o resultado da expressão em todo elemento que o `Find()` filtra é verdadeiro, então não filtra nada, passa tudo. Veja se pode só eliminar o `Find()`.

Só não afirmo porque pode depender do provedor do LINQ e sem ele algo pode dar errado, mas em geral não deveria ter utilidade alguma e pode só fazer:

```
List<Tipo1> tipo = await context.MeuMetodo.ToListAsync();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/True.cs).

Ou nem isso.

A não ser que tenha algo que eu não sei.

Comment: Se tirar o Find() dá erro

Comment: Foi o que falei, o *provider* pode exigir.